# Is there a phrase or idiom for a physically attractive person who lacks charisma or personality?

Tags: phrase-requests, idiom-requests

Sort of the opposite of 'more than a pretty face'. Are there others aside from 'just a pretty face'?

For context, the character this applies to is paraded around at social events by their parents for their appearance and goes out of their way to demonstrate their intelligence and charisma so that others don't mistake them for just physically attractive. The sentence right now is:

*No one could ever accuse me of being a pretty face lacking charisma.*

This will be something that comes up several times in the story, so I'm looking for a variety of ways to phrase it.

Comment: By "attractive person", I assume that you mean someone is simply physically attractive because to me "attractive" is a package that includes an engaging personality.

Comment: There's a word: superficial. But I'm guessing this is a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Redd Foxx, the late comedic actor, was known to say, "Beauty is only skin deep, but ugly is to the bone."

Here are some words to describe a handsome or beautiful person who does not have the charisma or personality to match. (Not all the words convey the idea of beauty in combination with a lack of charisma):

- shallow
- vacuous
- one-dimensional
- superficial
- skin-deep
- depthless
- lacking in depth
- empty
- [flawlessly dull](https://www.businessinsider.com/beautiful-people-are-boring-study-2012-10)
- [characterless conformity](https://www.businessinsider.com/beautiful-people-are-boring-study-2012-10)

Comment: these are exactly what i was looking for! thank you very much!

Comment: @dontcallmekoko: You're welcome, I'm sure! Don L.

Answer (score 3):

***[be just a pretty face.](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/be+just+a+pretty+face)***

> To be physically attractive but lack any distinguishing achievements, intelligence, abilities, or other personal characteristics.
>
> - *Tiffany might be popular because of her looks now, but once we're out
>   of college she's going to be just a pretty face.*

(The Free Dictionary)

Answer (score 1):

Arm Candy,
Eye Candy,
Trophy 'wife'

These all carry the implication that the person is primarily important for their looks. It doesn't say that they explicitly lack personality or charisma,  more that they're not relevant.

Collins dictionary :

Eye candy is used to refer to people or things that are attractive to look at but are not interesting in other ways.

https://books.google.it/books?id=beolDwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=eye+candy&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjLxfzpktvnAhXioVwKHb1tD-oQ6wEIOTAC#v=onepage&q=eye%20candy&f=false

@Lambie - point proved? :)

Comment: Sorry but: WHAT ABOUT MEN? [it merited shouting! :)]

Comment: Eye candy gets used for men.   I get called it all the time.

Comment: Oh my, how about that? :)

Comment: ohh, I'd somehow completely forgotten about arm and eye candy. Thanks for the assist, will definitely use that one at some point.